# How to test a BuildProvider

Tags: asp.net, codedom, buildprovider

I have created a simple BuildProvider as a starting point, and althogh I get no errors, I don't have access to the generated class either. In fact, i don't know if my BuildProvider was even invoked. Is there a way to debug a BuildProvider? How do I know if there is a problem with my CodeDom or if it's something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found is to write a unit test and debug it that way.